Radeon Pro 5700W not working on Optiplex 7090 with Ubuntu 24.04
I'm trying to install a Radeon Pro 5700W on a Dell Optiplex 7090 with Ubuntu 24.04 HWE as a video card, using amdgpu, with usecase graphics. After various misadventures I've got it installing without any error messages, but it isn't actually recognizing the video card. That is, the monitor simply isn't getting a signal. Fortunately the integrated video chip is still working.
sudo lshw -c video only lists the iGPU.
The appropriate line in /etc/default/grub is:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
Results of dkms status:
amdgpu/6.10.5-2095006.24.04, 6.8.0-51-generic, x86_64: installed

Results of uname -r:
6.8.0-51-generic

sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04
sudo add-apt-repository -y -s deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main universe
sudo apt install ./amdgpu-install_6.2.60203-1_all.deb
amdgpu-install -y --usecase=graphics,rocm
sudo usermod -a -G render,video [username]

I also tried:
sudo amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics,rocm --no-32

I've hit a wall.  Can anyone help?
